# Save DataGridColumn Sort property into Isolated Storage

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, isolatedstorage

I have a Datagrid whose column properties had to be saved automatically when changed. I am using ISOLATED STORAGE Settings to achieve this. As of now I am storing the DISPLAY INDEX property of the DataGrid Column.

In my code behind I am trying to push the settings along with the DataGridName as follows

```
List<GridColumnSettings> settings = new List<GridColumnSettings>();
for (int index = 0; index < dcDataGrid.Columns.Count; index++)
            {
                DataGridColumn column = dcDataGrid.Columns[index];
                SettingsViewModel.GridColumnSettings setting = new GridColumnSettings(column.DisplayIndex, index);
                settings.Add(setting);
            }
**SendTemplatesSettingsViewModel.SaveSettings(settings, "dcBrowserDataGrid")**
```

The SaveSettings method looks liks this

```
    public class SendTemplatesSettingsViewModel
        {

            public class GridColumnSettings
            {
                public int Index { get; set; } //Managing the column ordering of the DataGrid

                public int DisplayIndex { get; set; } //Store the Index/order of the column in the underlying datasource/ViewModel.

                public GridColumnSettings(int columnIndex, int displayIndex)
                {
                    this.DisplayIndex = columnIndex;
                    this.Index = displayIndex;
                }
            }
public void SaveSettings(List<SendTemplatesSettingsViewModel.GridColumnSettings> settings, string gridName)
        {
            mySettings.SetSetting<List<GridColumnSettings>>(gridName, settings);
        }
```

The SetSettings method is just instantiating the ISOLATED Storage and adding the values.

I would also like to store the **Sorting order of the columns**, but I am not able to find the right property to do so. Hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a collection view source as the data grid source then read/write to the SortDescriptions property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx